# Fade in, fade out not working in MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to make an effect of fade in, fade out using alpha and motionLayout, but it seems that it's not working.

This is the imageView that I want to fade.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tijeras"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/tijeras"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tijeras" />
    </android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

And this is the motion file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Transition
        app:duration="2000"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
                android:alpha="1.0"/>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="50"
                app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
                android:alpha="0.0"/>
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/tijeras"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"/>
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/tijeras"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"/>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

I can see the image, but it's not doing the alpha in and out. Any idea? Do I need to trigger it for starting?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have set the alpha as 1.0 `android:alpha="1.0"` on both the start and end `ConstraintSet`.

You can more easily set the alpha to update with a `CustomAttribute` by removing alpha from the `KeyAttribute` and placing the following below your `Transition` element

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@+id/tijeras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo">
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="alpha"
            motion:customFloatValue="0.0" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@+id/tijeras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo">
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="alpha"
            motion:customFloatValue="1.0" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that i have found the problem and the solution. So you are defining two ConstraintSet (start, end) and in both alpha = 1, it means that your view is visible in both of them right ? Now let's see your KeyFrameSet

```
<KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="0"
            app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
            android:alpha="1.0"/>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
            android:alpha="0.0"/>
    </KeyFrameSet>
```

You're saying that at framePosition = 0 your view is visible (alpha=1), then in the middle of your transition (framePosition = 50 ) you are hiding your view (alpha=0). It means that when you are at framePosition = 100 (end of your transition) the alpha will be 1 again because in your ConstraintSet (end) is equal to 1.

So try to change it like this, instead of 50, framePosition = 100

```
<KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="0"
            app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
            android:alpha="1.0"/>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="100"
            app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
            android:alpha="0.0"/>
    </KeyFrameSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need setting a `CustomAttribute`, this solution should work:

### BaseView

```
<!-- Other views -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tijeras"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/tijeras"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tijeras" />
```

### Content Scene

```
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
     <Transition
        app:duration="2000"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end">

        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="50"
                app:motionTarget="@id/tijeras"
                android:alpha="0.0"/> <!-- Set alpha to zero -->
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/tijeras" <!-- without + -->
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.0" <!-- set alpha to zero -->
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"/>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```